# .Net RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression Don't allow names that begin with A, The, An

Tags: .net, validation

I've a VendorName textbox on a web page.  I'm using .Net RegularExpression validation to restrict users from entering vendor name that being with a, an, or the followed by space.  Case doesn't matter.

Example:  Following names shouldn't be allowed
**The** Microsoft Company,
**an** Excalibur,
**a** Dream Come True

This is what I'm using for ValidationExpression
ValidationExpression="^(?!the).+"

This is catching "the" in "the microsoft" but is also preventing user from using "Theodore company".

I started of only with catching "the" and then will add other words once I've this working.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `(?!the )` won't work?

Comment: Seems a bit weird. I can think of lots of organizations that choose to name themselves with an article as the first word.

Comment: @Will No, it doesn't work.  Thanks

Comment: @Damien  You are correct, but we are trying to cleanup our Vendorlist by removing A, An, The from beginning so that users can search for vendors better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for word boundary.

Take a look at [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
"^(?!the\b).+";// \b is what you're looking for
```

Comment: I tried adding flag i for case insensitive and also two other words "a" and "an" like "^(?![the|a|an]\bi).+"  This didn't work

Comment: Try this "^(?i)(?!(the|a|an)\b).+"

Comment: Thanks Sriram.  It is not working.  It's allowing a|an|the regardless of the case

Comment: Yes, it is not working for me.. this is what i've                   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="VendorNameInvalidBegin" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtVendorName" 
                     CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="A, An, The are not allowed to start the vendor name with."
               ToolTip="A, An, The are not allowed to start the vendor name with." ValidationGroup="VendorValidationGroup"
                     ValidationExpression="^(?i)(?!(the|a|an)\b).+">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: I read somewhere that (?i) is not supported on client side so I even tried setting EnableClientScript="false"

Comment: Hmmm add @ before your string @"^(?i)(?!(the|a|an)\b).+"

Comment: I got invalid tag formation error from .net.  BTW, what you suggested does work at http://regexhero.net/tester/  For some reason not working for me when used in Regular Expression Validator

Comment: Try this "^(?i)(?!(the|a|an)\\b).+" added \\b to escape \

Comment: That didn't work either.  I don't think there is anything wrong with any of the solutions you've suggested.  For some reason (?i) doesn't work with .net RegularExpressionValidator.  This is what I got it working.. 
"^(?!((t|T)(h|H)(e|E)|(a|A)|(a|A)(n|N))\b).+".  Thank you so much for your help.